# Android - JsonException on httppost

Tags: android, json

i'm trying to connect my app with my db.

I make this script php:

```
<?php

/*ci colleghiamo al database(attenti perchè se lavorate in locale 
l'host è 10.0.2.2 e non 127.0.0.1)*/
 mysql_connect("localhost","mydb","")
    or die("Impossibile connettersi al server MySQL.\n"); 
//selezioniamo il db a cui ci vogliamo connettere
mysql_select_db("mydb")
    or die("Impossibile aprire il database.\n");
//creo la tabella nel database
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`survey` (
                    `Museum_ID` INT NOT NULL,
                `Game_ID` INT NOT NULL,
                `Vote` INT NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (`Museum_ID`))
                ENGINE = InnoDB;"); 
$idMuseum = $_POST['Museum_ID'];
$idGame = $_POST['Game_ID'];
$Vote = $_POST['Vote']
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mydb`.`survey` (`Museum_ID`, `Game_ID`, `Vote`) VALUES    ($idMuseum, $idGame, $Vote);");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$data = $row[0];
if($data){
echo $data;


mysql_close();
?>
```

and this is my Java code:

```
public class MakePost extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

     @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //toggleUI(0);

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Survey.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Sending data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

     protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {

            List<NameValuePair> parametriDaInviare = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            JSONObject json = null;
            int success = -1;
            updatesAv = false;


            try {
                if(checkedButton == R.id.lowChoise){
                    //aggiungo alla lista parametri il voto
                    parametriDaInviare.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Vote", "1"));
                    parametriDaInviare.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Museum_ID", "1"));
                    parametriDaInviare.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Game_ID", "1"));

                     // get JSON Object by using POST method
                    json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_Survey, "POST", parametriDaInviare);             
                    try
                    {
                        Log.d("PHP Response", json.toString());
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if(success == 1)
                        {   
                            popupWindow.dismiss();
                            updatesAv =true;

                        }
                        else {
                            updatesAv = false;
                        }
                        Log.d("UPDATES CHECK", "RESULT: " + updatesAv);


                    }catch (JSONException e) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        updatesAv = false;
                    }
                }
                if(checkedButton == R.id.mediumChoise){
                    //do something

                    parametriDaInviare.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Vote", "2"));
                    parametriDaInviare.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Museum_ID", "1"));
                    parametriDaInviare.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Game_ID", "1"));                     
                     // get JSON Object by using POST method
                    json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_Survey, "POST", parametriDaInviare);             
                    try
                    {
                        Log.d("PHP Response", json.toString());
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if(success == 1)
                        {   
                            popupWindow.dismiss();
                            updatesAv =true;

                        }
                        else {
                            updatesAv = false;
                        }
                        Log.d("UPDATES CHECK", "RESULT: " + updatesAv);


                    }catch (JSONException e) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        updatesAv = false;
                    }
                }
                if(checkedButton == R.id.highChoise){
                    //do something

                    parametriDaInviare.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Vote", "3"));
                    parametriDaInviare.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Museum_ID", "1"));
                    parametriDaInviare.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Game_ID", "1"));                      // get JSON Object by using POST method
                    json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_Survey, "POST", parametriDaInviare);             
                    try
                    {
                        Log.d("PHP Response", json.toString());
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if(success == 1)
                        {   
                            popupWindow.dismiss();
                            updatesAv =true;

                        }
                        else {
                            updatesAv = false;
                        }
                        Log.d("UPDATES CHECK", "RESULT: " + updatesAv);


                    }catch (JSONException e) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        updatesAv = false;
                    }
                }



            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                // da implementare
            }



     return null;    
     }


     protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all data
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }
```

when i sent the data i have this error:

```
11-03 13:20:55.918: E/JSON Parser(11238): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

i have not many experience with php and i don't know if there is some error in my code.
can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: I think the output of url is not json. Some warning or error message is present in it. Please confirm after checking it in browser.

Comment: In browser i have this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in mydb/survey.php on line 20.

line 20 is the insert query

Comment: Log your httpResponse and post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change
    echo $data

to 
    echo json_encode($data);

add a semicolon at the end of this row

$Vote = $_POST['Vote']   ;

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all you should Remove `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);`
   this is an  insert nothing to fetch ! not to mention you are mixing
   mysqli and mysql extension
2. Use mysqli extenstions, you are exposed to SQL injection
3. Finally  `echo $data;` is not JSON it will break your app since you
   atttempt to parse json data.
4. Missing semicolon `$Vote = $_POST['Vote'];`

```
if(!$result){
    echo json_encode(array('success'=> 0));
}else{
    echo json_encode(array('success'=> 1));
}
```

Comment: the problem was the semicolon, and the echo.. i solved my problem when i see the @Luke answer, just a few minutes before your's.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is mostly passing back HTML to the app which then trying to parse it fails. As the error says the response starts with br. Please check if your getting proper response from your server

Comment: In browser i have this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in mydb/survey.php on line 20. line 20 is the insert query

Comment: Yes, thats the problem. The SQL query fails, check the SQL query again please

Comment: how i can simulate the post in my browser?

Comment: You could try using POSTMAN to simulate the request on the browser

Comment: with postman i sent a post and this is the error:

<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in 
<b>mydb/survey.php</b> on line 
<b>20</b>
<br />.

If i try to send (1,1,1) in my database, without using the post, i have no error :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your php response to like this
echo Json_encode($data);
because it is sending the plane html data that why you are getting JSONEXCEPTION

Comment: if i do : if($data){
echo json_encode $data;
}

i have this error in my browser : 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in mydb/survey.php on line 24

Comment: Check your sql queries.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a semicolon in wrong position in your query:

Change this: `VALUES ($idMuseum, $idGame, $Vote);");`

**to**  `VALUES ($idMuseum, $idGame, $Vote)");`

2. As amit kumar already mentioned, you should use `echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: if i comments the post , and i insert the value (1,1,1) in my db i have no error with the browser. the memicolon is not the problem :(

Comment: are the values 1,1,1 inserted successfully in your db?